# Why is the Lagrangian specifically a function of $v^2$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I've been reading "L. D. Landau, E.M. Lifshitz - Mechanics (Volume 1)" and he justifies the fact that the Lagrangian is a function of $v^2$ with the fact that space is isotropic - that is, direction does not matter. My question is: could we choose $L$ to be a function of $|v|$ or $v^4$? I know that, if we choose $v^2$ and assume $v_0<<1$, (note: in the book, $v_0$ is a factor that relates one inertial frame of reference to another) we can nicely cancel out $v_0^2$. However, is this the only reason? Could we achieve the same results choosing other "v"s?

Comment: The Same Question has been asked  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/212909/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The speed $v\equiv |\vec{\bf v}|\geq 0$ is by definition the magnitude of the velocity $\vec{\bf v}$. Any function of speed $v$, or say $v^4$, can be easily rewritten as a function of $v^2 \equiv |\vec{\bf v}|^2$, or vice-versa. The latter form $f(v^2)$ is preferable when one tries to partial differentiate wrt. a velocity component in order to avoid square roots.
2. For why the Lagrangian for a free particle is such function $f(v^2)$, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23098/2451) related Phys.SE post.